# Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, extjs

I saw this question been asked several times but those answers are not helping me out. I want to remove an element for which I'm using the following function:

```
 removeCriteria: function(criteria) {
            criteria.el.slideOut('t', {
                easing: 'eastOutStrong',
                duration: 0.15,
                remove: true,
                callback: function() {
                    this.criteria.remove(criteria);
                    this.remove(criteria);
                    this.doLayout();
                    Ext.each(this.criteria, function(c) {
                      c.updateTitle(); });
                    this.getCriteriaMenuItemByType(criteria).show();
                    this.fireEvent('criteriaremove', this, criteria);
                },
                scope: this
            });
        },
  addCriteria: function(type) {
            var criteria = this.createCriteria(type);
            this.criteria.push(criteria);
            this.add(criteria);
            if (!this.collapsed) {
                this.doLayout();
                var self = this;
               
                criteria.el.slideIn('t', {
                    easing: 'easeOut',
                    duration: 0.2,
                    callback: function() {
                        this.fireEvent('criteriaadd', this, criteria);
                    },
                    scope: this
                });
            } else {
                this.fireEvent('criteriaadd', this, criteria);
            }
          
            return criteria;
        },
```

where Criteria and type in the above code is an object:
[image]
at this `this.doLayout();` it throws an error, i tried debugging it through extjs but in vain.
I'm able to remove the object successfully, however when I try to add back the same object, I get this error:

[image]

any ideas???
Please let me know for more info

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can put a Sencha Fiddle with your issue?

Comment: You will see lots of these errors with ExtJS 3.4 code having complex nested layouts. Needless to say, removing this.doLayout() will not work as it is there for updating the component to latest state. From the error all it seems like ExtJS object that is present in tree has been detached from the dom. Can you please post a Fiddle to investigate more?

Comment: `.contains()` is `.classList()` function.  It needs called on document node (i.e. a result  of document.querySelector, document.getElementByClass, etc).  Look for `someVar.contains` and change it to `someVar.classList.contains()`